# Getting message " Test run finished: 0 Tests (0 Passed, 0 Failed, 0 Skipped) run in < 1 ms"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit

I am trying to run my test case in visual studio. But it just builds the project and no test runs.
In test window it shows

> "Test run finished: 0 Tests (0 Passed, 0 Failed, 0 Skipped) run in < 1 ms"

In warning I am getting

> "There was a conflict between "nunit.framework, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2638cd05610744eb" and "nunit.framework, Version=3.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2638cd05610744eb"."

But in nuget package manager only `nunit.framework, Version=3.2.0.0`, is present.

Comment: Check the dependencies of the test project. Maybe some of your tested projects (or other references) have a reference to another version of NUnit.

Comment: Open your project file (ex. : .vbproj) in notepad and check references, If you find any extra reference then remove it.

Comment: Show your csproj or vbproj file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show us the code.

This can happen if you try to test an `Async` method. You must return a `Task` to the test explorer. You can't return a `void` or `Sub`.